# Pygame Python font

Tags: python, pygame, width, glyph

I have a question regarding the glyph a font and the pygame width of a font yesterday i some code regarding this here is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
i = 0
text = "hello how are you?"
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    letter = text[i]
    text_1 = font.render(letter, True, (255, 255, 255))

    bw, bh = font.size(letter)
    glyph_rect = pygame.mask.from_surface(text_1).get_bounding_rects()
    # print(glyph_rect)
    if glyph_rect:
        gh = glyph_rect[0].height
        print(f"{glyph_rect[0]}")
        print(f'letter {letter}  bitmap height: {bh}  glyph height: {gh} width = {glyph_rect[0].width} width_2 = {bw}')

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(text_1, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

    i += 1
    run = i < len(text)

pygame.quit()
# win.blit(text_1, (0, 0))
```

I know why the glyph height is diffrent because i asked that in a question and i got a answer for that but why is the glyph width always a bit less than the actual width? Can someone explain me in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width is different because there is a space between characters when they are connected to words.
`glyph_rect[0].width` is the width of the glyph. `bw` is the width of the bitmap. The glyph does not fill the entire bitmap and has some space on both sides.

[image]

---

You can investigate this with the following program (each letter is displayed for 1 second):

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 200)
i = 0
text = "hello how are you?"
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    letter = text[i]
    text_1 = font.render(letter, True, (0, 0, 0))
    text_draw = font.render(letter, True, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))

    bw, bh = font.size(letter)
    glyph_rect = pygame.mask.from_surface(text_1).get_bounding_rects()
    if glyph_rect:
        gh = glyph_rect[0].height
        print(f"{glyph_rect[0]}")
        print(f'letter {letter}  bitmap height: {bh}  glyph height: {gh} width = {glyph_rect[0].width} width_2 = {bw}')

    win.fill((128, 128, 128))
    win.blit(text_draw, (100, 100))
    for r in glyph_rect:
        draw_rect = r.move(100, 100)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), draw_rect, 3)
    pygame.display.update()

    i += 1
    run = i < len(text)
    clock.tick(1)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining me biitmap font and bitmap and glyphs and many other things.

Comment: so the charecter " " has no connecting pixels with it as it is the background so i will get an empty list as glyph_rect

Comment: so the charecter " " has no connecting pixels with it as it is the background so i will get an empty list as glyph_rect

Comment: @Rohit12345 Yes, for " " the list is empty. For "?" the list has 2 elements.

Comment: ok ya it has two elements because there is a space between the . in the question mark right

Comment: Only you answer these type of trick question with pygame no body else answer these question thanks a lot.